# How can I access tab list in a process?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, process, tabs, microsoft-edge

I faced a problem about selenium automation which is is about alert message. There is a website which has many pop-ups after login, and also has alert message in some cases. The problem is that everything stops when the alert is occured till I accept the alert, while one of pop-up got the focus and main window pointer. Webdriver doesn't work in this case, and I get the error below if I try to handle the driver:

The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50610/session/100ef050ba8ac8cdb90845332b1c8178/window timed out after 60 seconds.

The process architecture is below, and every tabs are actually window.

[image]
탭 means tab, the main window is "about:blank" in the pic.

[image]
The shape of the windows.

I think I can handle this problem if I can access the window having alert message. How can I access the specific tab window in the process?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the specific tab window in the process?

You can use `switchTo()` to switch to a specific tab. Something like this:

```
var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"E:\EdgeDriver\msedgedriver-114.0.1823.67.exe");
            var options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);
            String link1 = "https://www.google.com";
            String link2 = "https://www.bing.com";

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link1);
            var handles = driver.WindowHandles;
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open('"+ link2 +"');");
            //switch to first tab
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles[0]);
         
            Console.WriteLine("Title: " + driver.Title.ToString() + "   ProcessID: " + service.ProcessId);
```